# Make takeUntil first trigger the remove handlers of fromEvent first

Tags: rxjs

I have a pipeline that ends with takeUntil, the problem is `switchMap` is getting triggered because the `combineLatest` is not canceled till the `tap`s inside `takeUntil` end.

My pseudocode:

```
combineLatest(
    fromEventPattern(handler => {
        document.addEventListener('disconnect', handler, false);
        console.log('added');
    },
    handler => {
        document.removeEventListener('disconnect', handler, false);
        console.log('removed');
    }
).pipe(
    switchMap(() => { 
        console.log('SWITCH MAP TRIGGERED!');
        return EMPTY;
    ]),
    takeUntil(
        mySubject.pipe(
            filter(type => type === 'LOGOUT'),
            tap(() => console.log('got logout, so do logout calls'),
            tap(() => document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('disconnect')))
        )
    )
)
```

Trigger the cancelation with:

```
mySubject.next({ type: 'LOGOUT' });
```

The problem I'm having is that it's not removing the event listenrs until after the `tap`s in `takeUntil` finish. Due to this, the dispatch of the `"disconnect"` event is triggering the `switchMap` to trigger again. I want things to cancel immediately as the `filter` in `takeUntil` is met, and then it should do that final action of `dispatchEvent('disconnect')`.

Comment: Why you're trying to dispatch event even?

`fromEventPattern` automatically invokes the second callback when the source complete. a better approach to use takeUntil as the first operator.

Comment: Thanks @Ezzabuzaid - in my actual code, I do a `logout()` here. And this cases the socket to disconnect, and in the `combineLatest` I am listening to `"disconnect"` because this observable is in charge of re-connecting on disconnect. So I mimiced it with the `dispatchEvent` in my psuedocode above. I tried `takeUntil` before the `switchMap` but its still triggering the `switchMap`. :(

Comment: I guess you could just wrap `document.dispatchEvent(...)` with `setTimeout()` so it'll be calle asynchronously.

Comment: I don't think that there's any benefit from using `combineLatest` in your case, you can pipe directly to `fromEventPattern`

for a quick and simple solution try to use plain js code now and progressively use rxjs

Comment: @martin I'm doing that as workaround but I don't like how its not the rxjs way :(

Comment: @Ezzabuzaid my actual code has more stuff in `combineLatest`.